# How to convert a DataTable into JSON in spotfire using IronPython?

Tags: python, json, ironpython, spotfire

I have a datatable present in Spotfire, I need to convert it into JSON object. I have below working piece of code but I need code that works faster.

```
import clr
import sys
clr.AddReference('System.Web.Extensions')
from System.Web.Script.Serialization import JavaScriptSerializer
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import IndexSet
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataValueCursor

rowCount = MyTable.RowCount
rows = IndexSet(rowCount,True)
cols = MyTable.Columns
MyTableData=[]

for r in rows:
 list={}
 item={}
 for c in cols:
  item[c.Name] = c.RowValues.GetFormattedValue(r)
  list['MyData']=item
 MyTableData.append(list)

json=JavaScriptSerializer(MaxJsonLength=sys.maxint).Serialize(MyTableData)
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show? SO is not a coding service...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much overhead the last line has on your code, but if you are using myTableData result as a string to drive a javscript widget, you dont need it. Try replacing last line with

```
json=str(MyTableData)
```

and see how fast it is.